# How to do a secure register from my Android or iPhone app to my web services, using Facebook Login or Google+ Login in my mobile App

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a mobile app in Android and I wan to create Login with Facebook and Google+. But I need the USERS of the app will be register in my own web services.

So my cuestion is, if I get the Login with Facebook from my app (with Facebook SDK), then how I register this facebook user into my app??.

Obviously I can get the mail or username, but never the facebook password (obviously). So how is the correct and secure method to do that?

I think use the ID as if a password, but I do not think it's right.

For the Web Services I use Ruby on Rails. Greatings I hope somebody help me!

**Update**

Now I know Amazon AWS provided this function for mobile apps in amazon cognito:

https://aws.amazon.com/es/cognito/

Maybe is the best option, because is more secure and the programmer doesn't wasted time.

Comment: facebook uses oAuth, you should first try learning what is oauth and then you will have a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess after user successfully login  by facebook or google all you have to do is store users profile on server as registered user and in local database store status as logged in.

If user log out from your application clear local data, when next time user try to log in check whether entered ID exist on your server if yes login with respective platform (google/facebook) but this time dont create new profile but in local database again maintain status as Logged in

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is an open standard for authorization. OAuth provides client applications a 'secure delegated access' to server resources on behalf of a resource owner.

Basically facebook will provide you with an access_token that you can use to verify. Based on this verification you can use the ID to login the user.